# JMeter is skipping first row of data in CSV file

Tags: csv

I have a script that is reading data from a CSV file but it's skipping the first row of data. The file is basically a header with data below.
ex: 
 1. Case
 2. 234235245
 3. 256745673

What's happening when I use the variable ${Case}, is it's pulling Line 3 then Line 4 and so on rather than starting with Line 2. I have Recycle on EOF set to true so it's getting Line 2 after reading through the rest of the file but it should be getting Line 2 first.

- CSV Data Set Config
- Filename: ${FileLoc}
- File Enconding: blank
- File Enconding: blank
- Variable Names (comma-delimited): blank
- Ignore first line (only used if Variable Names is not empty): False
- Delimiter (user '\t' for tab: ,
- Allow quoted data?: False
- Recycle on EOF?: True
- Stop thread on EOF?: False
- Sharing mode: All threads

Any help is appreciated. I searched for an answer but the things I found were either caused by some custom coding or referring to skipping the header data which is working correctly for me as I have the Variable Names field blank.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was a user error (I'm the user haha). I had the file in the correct place (inside a loop) **and** the incorrect place (outside a loop).

I had been doing some troubleshooting and was copying the file to different places to see if it was part of the issue. When I went back to my original-ish setup and re-enabled the file in the first location, I forgot to disable the file in the other location.